# Can one drop the retracts in the definition of anodyne extensions?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Definition: Anodyne extensions(i.e. acyclic cofibration) of simplicial sets are the closure of horn inclusions under transfinite composition, pushouts, and retracts.

The composition and pushouts can be easily thought of as attaching cells. My question: can we drop the requirement of retracts? Do we have a conterexample show that retract is must needed?

Comment: If you look at the proof of Proposition 4.2 in [Goerss and Jardine, Ch. I], you will see that retractions are used. This is not quite a counterexample but shows that the property is useful.

Comment: @ZhenLin But here I believe we can actually write it as a pushout: $\Lambda^{n+1}_k\to\Delta^{n+1}$ is a pushout of $\Lambda^n_k \times\Delta^1 \cup \Delta^n \times\Lambda^1_0\to  \Delta^n\times \Delta^1$.

Comment: How do you propose to do this for $k = n + 1$?

Comment: @ZhenLin You could use $\Lambda^1_1$ instead of $\Lambda^1_0$.

Comment: I really don't know anything about anodyne extensions, but I happen to have read some parts of the first chapter of [Cisinski's thesis](http://www.math.univ-toulouse.fr/~dcisinsk/ast.pdf) (in french), and remark 1.3.11 could help you : it is said that the class of anodyne extensions $\mathsf {An}$ is exactly the class formed by the retracts of transfinite compositions of the pushouts of the morphisms in $\Lambda$.

Comment: @Pece That can be the definition. Retract is also important in the small object argument. My question is asking a counterexample or a proof that retract can be dropped in the definition of anodyne extensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are anodyne extensions that are not obtained using only pushouts and coproducts. The following example is due to my colleague.

Let $p$ be the composite $\Lambda^2_0 \to \Delta^2 \overset{s^1}{\to} \Delta^1$, where $s^1 : \Delta^2 \to \Delta^1$ is the morphism corresponding to the (degenerate) 2-simplex $0 \to 1 \to 1$. Form the following pushout square:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\Lambda^2_0 @>{p}>> \Delta^1 \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\Delta^2 @>>{x}> X
\end{CD}$$
Let $d^0 : \Delta^1 \to \Delta^2$ be the morphism corresponding to the edge $1 \to 2$,  let $e : \Lambda^2_1 \to X$ be the composite $\Lambda^2_1 \to \Delta^2 \overset{x}{\to} X$ and form the following pushout square:
$$\begin{CD}
\Lambda^2_1 @>{e}>> X \\
@VVV @VVV \\
\Delta^2 @>>{y}> Y
\end{CD}$$
By construction, $\Delta^1 \to X \to Y$ is an anodyne extension, so by the 2-out-of-3 property, $Y \to \Delta^0$ is a weak homotopy equivalence, and hence any morphism $\Delta^1 \to Y$ whatsoever is a weak homotopy equivalence.

Let $d^1 : \Delta^1 \to \Delta^2$ be the morphism corresponding to the edge $0 \to 2$. Then composite $\Delta^1 \overset{d^1}{\to} \Delta^2 \overset{y}{\to} Y$ is an anodyne extension, and it cannot be obtained using only coproducts and pushouts of horn inclusions. To see this, it is useful to have a more explicit description of $Y$:

- $Y$ has two vertices, say $a$ and $b$.
- $Y$ has three non-degenerate edges: $\alpha, \gamma : a \to b$ and one edge $\beta : b \to b$.
- $Y$ has two non-degenerate 2-simplices: $x$, with edges $\beta, \alpha, \alpha$, and $y$, with edges $\beta, \gamma, \alpha$.

The anodyne extension in question is the morphism $f : \Delta^1 \to Y$ corresponding to $\gamma$. If it were possible to express $f$ using coproducts and pushouts of horn inclusions, then we must only use horn inclusions of the form $\Lambda^2_k \to \Delta^2$; but one can verify that there is no possible commutative diagram of the form below,
$$\begin{CD}
\Lambda^2_k @>>> \Delta^1 @>{f}>> Y \\
@VVV @VVV @| \\
\Delta^2 @>>> Y' @>>> Y
\end{CD}$$
where the left square is a pushout square and $Y' \to Y$ is a monomorphism. This proves the claim.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is not just $X = \Delta^1$ and and $x = s^1$?